# How to get the SUM of a column that is created from a join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, sum

I have 3 tables, PRODUCT_INVENTORY, CUSTOMER_INFORMATION, and SALES_ORDER.

Im using the following SQL to generate a Monthly revenue report

```
SELECT 
PRODUCT_INVENTORY.UNIT_PRICE, SALES_ORDER.UNITS_SOLD , SALES_ORDER.SALE_DATE, 
PRODUCT_INVENTORY.UNIT_PRICE * SALES_ORDER.UNITS_SOLD AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM PRODUCT_INVENTORY
INNER JOIN SALES_ORDER

ON PRODUCT_INVENTORY.PRODUCT_ID = SALES_ORDER.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE SALES_ORDER.SALE_DATE >= '01-JAN-09'
AND SALES_ORDER.SALE_DATE <= '31-JAN-09';
```

This is the data Im getting back.

```
UNIT_PRICE      UNITS_SOLD      SALE_DATE       TOTAL_SALES
----------      ----------      ---------       -----------
900             2               11-JAN-09       1800 
1700            2               12-JAN-09       3400
```

My question is how do I add the values in the new TOTAL_SALES column and have it display something like this?

```
UNIT_PRICE   UNITS_SOLD     SALE_DATE       TOTAL_SALES
----------   ----------     ---------       -----------
900          2              11-JAN-09        1800 
1700         2              12-JAN-09        3400

                                            TOTAL_REVENUE 
                                            5200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTE or subquery

```
 With CTE
 As
 ( 
    Your query
 )
 Select sum(total_sales) as total_revenue , 
 From CTE
```